# Java: Unexpected exit during write

Tags: java, error-handling, io

Lets say I have a java program writing out a large JSON taking up some time. Is there a way to determine if the program exits unexpectedly on the next startup to determine if my JSON is corrupted?

Comment: You can write a log file, in which you can add an entry if the program completes sucessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the file after your process is complete:

```
try
{
    File outputFile = ...;
    someLongRunningProcess( outputFile );
    File successfulFile = ...
    outputFile.renameTo( successfulFile );
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    ...
}
```

If you don't have a `successfulFile` when you restart, your previous run wasn't successful.

Just keep the `renameTo` operation within a single file system so it's a simple, almost instantaneous atomic operation instead of any implied copy.

Comment: Thanks for this! Renaming files slipped my mind for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Can you, please, explain clearer? Do you mean starting up again after JVM exits? If that is what you meant you will need a file based flag for that.

```
 String expectedFlag="Good Exit";

 void afterExit(){
        //always overwrite whatever is in this file 
        //write flag value to a txt file
 }

 boolean beforeStarting(){
      String flagText = readFromFlagFile();
      if(expectedFlag.equals(flagText)){

          return true;

       }

       return false;
 }
```

Comment: yes this is question and the solution I am going for. But how would I implement this?